# sencha build is not loading an application

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

i am trying to build `sencha touch app` so that later on i can integrate it with `phonegap` and run it as an `android` native app.

but when i run following command

```
sencha app build package
```

there is not any error but the build package contains **blank** `app.js` file , and when i try to access it using browser the application keeps loading only.

if i try following commands still the application keeps loading endlessly

```
sencha app build production or sencha app build testing
```

Comment: Did you find a solution? This is happening to me almost 2 years later...

Answer (score 0):

Try to look at your `app.js` file and check if a `//<debug>` tag (if present), it is followed by the `//</debug>` closing tag:

```
//<debug>
Ext.Loader.setPath({
    'Ext': 'touch/src',
    'Ext.ux': 'libs/ux'
});
//</debug>
```

It seems that in earlier version of sencha command, after a version upgrade it makes some error parsing existing project files